# Print the componenents of list if it it satisfies some argument from another list

Tags: python-3.x

I have two lists with same length and I want to print out components of list b if it is greater than the square of the same component in list a

```
a = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

For example:

```
if b[0] > (a[0])**2:
   print (b[0])
```

Desired output is a list

```
[10, 11]
```

because `10 > 2**2 and 11 > 3**2`

```
>>> a = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> b = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
>>> for x, y in zip(a, b):
...     if y > x**2:
...        print(b)
```

I think I am doing something wrong with the if statement? Any help

Comment: currently i beleive you print the whole list called b, change it to y, and if you want it as a list you need to append it to an empty list. :)

Comment: Yeah my mistake.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

```
print([b[i] for i in range(len(b)) if b[i] > a[i]**2])
```

gives:

```
[10,11]
```

and with your method:

```
print([i for w,i in zip(a,b) if i > w**2])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this also:

```
a = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14] 

for index, value in enumerate(b):
    if value > a[index]**2:
        print(value)
```